# Get custom attribute value in Observer

Tags: magento-1.7, attributes, checkout, event-observer

I have created a module which uses a Observer for the event 'checkout_onepage_controller_success_action'

I need to get the list of items in the order and get a custom attribute (the type is text).

So far I can load the order and get all items in that order:

```
$orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderIds);
$ordered_items = $order->getAllItems();
```

So far to get some of the attributes for each item in the order I do this:

```
foreach ($ordered_items as $item) {
    echo $item->getName()."<br />";
    echo $item->getSku();
}
```

These values are displaying fine. The problem is each product has a custom attribute with the code 'isbn_10' but I can't get the value to display. Some code I've tried is:

```
$item->getAttributeText('isbn_10');
$item->getIsbn10();
$item->getResource()->getAttribute('isbn_10')->getFrontend()->getValue($item);
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
$item->getProduct()->getAttributeText('isbn_10');
```

or

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId())->getAttributeText('isbn_10');
```

or

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId())->getData('isbn_10');
```

Comment: Hi Marius, I've tried these two methods but both are still not displaying anything. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @xx0f. I added an other suggestion. If that does not work, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: The last one worked, many thanks for your help.

Comment: I have been playing with Magento custom Attributes for last one year and I figured out a safest way to get custom attribute value. Here is the detailed tutorial http://scriptbaker.com/get-custom-attribute-value-in-magento/

Answer (score 0):

To add to this question am trying to add a column inside the invoice file now by editing the following file I managed to get an output but I struggle with the correct value from the database:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice/Default.php

    //draw Pick Location
    $lines[0][] = array(
        'text'  => Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split($this->getPickLocationValue($item), 25),
        'feed'  => 280,
        'align' => 'right'
    );
```

and the function that seems to be the most important:

```
/*
 * Return Value of custom attribute
 * */
private function getPickLocationValue($item)
{
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId())->getAttributeText('picklocation');

    if(!($return_location = $item->getPickLocation()))
        return 'N/A';
    else
        return $return_location;
}
```